# Xcode 7 Beta 4 Core Data error

Tags: core-data, xcode7-beta4

My app was working just fine, but today I went to test it out and a `cdtool cannot compile` started to appear and it just won't run at all. I don't know what to do. I tried deleting Xcode and reinstalling it, cleaning and building, but nothing. I even restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868017/xcode-7-xcdatamodeld-doesn-t-exist/33078239#33078239).

In my case, it was due to the unknown resource added in "Compile Sources" of "Build Phase".