# XCode 7: xcdatamodeld doesn’t exist

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

After updating to XCode 7 in order to support iOS9 I had the following build error

```
error: Cannot read bundle contents (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “VoIP.xcdatamodeld” doesn’t exist.
```

Build target myTitle of project myTitle with configuration Debug

> DataModelCompile Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myTitle.app/
>   /Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld
>       cd /Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/app/iPhone
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk
>   --iphoneos-deployment-target 7.0 --module myTitle /Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld
>   /Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/app/iPhone/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myTitle.app/
>
> /Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld:: error: Cannot
>   read bundle contents (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The
>   folder “VoIP.xcdatamodeld” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x7fd0f350f990
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/myself/MyDev/m1/app/VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder ), NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd0f350f940 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"})

How can I resolve it?

The only reference about this file in my project is this one (in the .project file)

```
/* Begin XCVersionGroup section */
                449367DE1338E89100DB4AC9 /* myTitle.xcdatamodeld */ = {
                        isa = XCVersionGroup;
                        children = (
                                449367DF1338E89100DB4AC9 /* VoIP.xcdatamodel */,
                        );
                        currentVersion = 449367DF1338E89100DB4AC9 /* VoIP.xcdatamodel */;
                        name = myTitle.xcdatamodeld;
                        path = ../../../../VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld;
                        sourceTree = "<group>";
                        versionGroupType = wrapper.xcdatamodel;
                };
/* End XCVersionGroup section */
```

No idea how it came from and why it worked w/o problems in previous xcode versions.

Comment: Have you checked whether the folder exists?

Comment: The folder VoIP/VoIP/VoIP.xcdatamodeld  does not exist. It never did.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - Find where this reference comes from and fix it.

Comment: @Abizern just updated my answer. I grepped the project hierarchy and I had only one reference in the project file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check **Compile Sources** under **Build Phases** for your Target setting described in the below image.

---

[image]

---

I saw all the resources carefully and found one resource without any path (an unknown resource, I don't know how it appeared there..). Remove it from there, clean the product and run.

The above was the only reason in my case..

Hope it helps you !!!

Comment: Just to add, either there may be resources without path OR resources with a wrong path.

Comment: Another thing to add - resources without path does NOT necessarily mean it should be removed (all resources in the project root directory doesn't have their paths), but those ones with a gray icon and dotted outlines are those "unknown" resources.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue when I stashed a new Model and unfortunately the selected solution did not work for me. What worked for me was: find the model file in your project folder in Finder ("ModelNameHere.xcdatamodeld"); right-button click and select "Show Package Contents". You will see all versions of the Model - delete the one that was not supposed to exist.

Comment: Same issue here. Created a second model but decided to start over. I then rolled back with git but somehow XCode kept the reference to the second data model even though is not actually shown anywhere on XCode itself (except for failing to build). The accepted answer didn't work for me, but when i did what @HeavenlyManBR suggests, i saw where XCode had kept the other model hidden from me.

Comment: This solution did work in 2020 using Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504). Thanks HeavenlyManBR and also @Jaun Carlos Ospina Gonzalez. The worst part is `git status` does not show this change.